# Webpack output bundle Systemjs

Tags: webpack, systemjs

I'm trying to bundle my app with webpack and then include it in a parent app with SystemJS and I am a little bit lost.

I have my bundle created and I've tried it converting it to commonjs / umd / amd setting libraryTarget.

In my parent app I can't include it via SystemJS, since it appears its not being registered.

Is there a way I can output my Webpack bundle in a SystemJs module?

Comment: Can you show a code snippet of how you are accessing it? It makes a difference if you are just including the bundle on the page vs loading it with System.import.

Answer (score 0):

the bundling is not just minified and unify js files.
the bundle config file is contained a package access information and etc.
so systemjs can't understand the webpack config but you can use system js bundle feature